# Printing lines in python

Tags: python, printing, cgi

How can i print lines in python like this

```
print " text here
text here

text here

line here"
```

I am trying cgi, so i dont have to use print to each line i have to print

thanks

Answer (score 2):

use triple quoted strings

```
print( """
Something 
You 
can
print
multi-line
""")
```

Comment: @Senthil, @meathook mentioned CGI, although it's unclear what he is after.  If it is truly CGI, then he needs `<BR>` tags.

Comment: How to add variables inside this string?

Comment: meathook - if you are using python3.2 just make it a function. Also as Mike points out, if you are using CGI and your display is HTML, you got to include `<BR>` the HTML line break for the output to be on different lines. (BTW, which cgi module for python are using for python3?)

Comment: @meathook, [See the Python Format docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: Ok, but i dont need to make a lot of "print("")"s to print each line

Comment: @meathook - it may just help to start with a tutorial.

Comment: @meathook, please accept Senthil's answer... this is a nice courtesy for the effort he put into the answers.